# Prevent Product Images From Downloading To Media Using External URLs During Import [Wordpress]

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, import, e-commerce, media

I have 100k+ products and each product has 5+ images. I have uploaded all images to google cloud storage and using it as external server for my images. Now, I need to import the products in my wordpress site. I defined all image urls in my csv, however, during the import, wordpress is downloading all the images to media which kills the purpose of taking images to external server. I want to keep images externally and don't want to import them to media.

Is there any way to it?

Comment: You just need to find a caching plugin compatible with WooCommerce, that can enable your Google cloud storage as a CDN for your medias (product images). Then this plugin should upload everything required to your Google cloud storage.

Comment: solved your problem? if so please share your solution kinda in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin "Featured Image from URL (FIFU)" solved the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).